# Oracle Database Connection in Grails 5

Tags: oracle, grails

I am trying to use an Oracle database to a Grails project. It works in a Grails 3 project, but I can't get it working with grails 5.

In application.yml I have:

```yaml
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    autoReconnect: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    logSql: false
    properties:
        maxActive: 50
        maxIdle: 25
        minIdle: 5
        initialSize: 5
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 60000
        maxWait: 10000
        testOnBorrow: true
        testWhileIdle: true
        testOnReturn: true
        validationQuery: "SELECT * FROM DUAL"

environments:
    development:
        dataSource: 
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx.xx.xx:1521:xxx
            username: 'xxx'
            password: 'xxx'
```

I also have the ojdbc7.jar in lib folder, and in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compileOnly fileTree(dir: 'lib/', include: '*.jar')
}
```

I have a domain, and I try to get results in a controller, but I have 0 results found, and the table contains data.

Any help, please? It works for me in a grails 3 application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ojdb7 is for java 7 I believe, grails 5 uses java 8 minimum so that could be an issue, what version is your oracle DB? You can check which jar you need here - https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html and add as a dependency rather than adding manually if possible e.g. for the latest ojdbc8 - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8/21.7.0.0

Comment: My oracle database is 11.2, and java 17. I have tried with ojdbc8 but the same result. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: No error message, only I can see I can't get results. Thank you.

Comment: What type of query are you running? Dynamic finder, criteria...? Could you simplify it to just select all from your table and print to console to begin with

Comment: "No error message, only I can see I can't get results. " - Does "I can't get results" mean that when you send a query to the database and you always get back an empty result?